# How to get additional properties of json object in js tree

Tags: jquery

i have added index node in json object now  i need to get that index on js tree click event.here obj.newAttributeThreatName is coming from service that what i want to show in tree structure.please check the code provided below:

```
var treeData = [];
var threatIndex = [];
var folders = {};

threatsArr.forEach(function(obj) {

    if (obj.newAttributeThreatName in folders) {
        console.log("if")
        treeData[folders[obj.newAttributeThreatName]].children.push({
            text : obj.newAttributeThreatName,
            index : obj.newAttributeThreatIndex
        });

    } else {
        console.log("else");
        folders[obj.newAttributeThreatName] = treeData.push({
            text : obj.newAttributeThreatName,
            index : obj.newAttributeThreatIndex,
            children : [ {
                text : obj.newAttributeThreatName,
                index : obj.newAttributeThreatIndex
            } ]
        }) - 1;
    }

});

var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(treeData);


var obj123 = JSON.parse(myJsonString);

$('#listThreat').jstree({
    'core' : {
        'data' : obj123

    },
    "plugins" : [

    "wholerow", "changed",

    ]
});

$('#listThreat').on('changed.jstree', function(e, data) {
    var i, j, r = [];
    for (i = 0, j = data.selected.length; i < j; i++) {
        r.push(data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).index);
    }

    console.log($("#listThreat").jstree("get_selected",true).attr("index"));
    console.log('Selected: ' + r.join(', '));
    $('#resultText').html('Selected: ' + r.join(', '));
}).jstree();
```

Comment: How about providing some content for threatsArr?

Comment: obj.newAttributeThreatIndex is already in threatsArr.as i have added this in treeData and getting this myJsonString but while sending this for jstree it is only taking specified format of json irrespective of my json data